# How do I compare two domain names in URL strings?

Tags: php, regex

Say if I have two strings

```
$first = 'http://www.example.com';
$second = 'www.example.com/';
```

How could I determine they match? I just care that the `example` part matches. I'm thinking some form of Regex pattern would match but I can't figure it out at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a regex if you're trying to evaluate structured data.  Regexes are not a magic wand you wave at every problem that happens to involve strings.  What if you have a URL like `http://www.some-other-domain.com/blah/blah/?www.example.com`?

If you're trying to match a domain name to a domain name, then break apart the URL to get the host and compare that.  In PHP, use the [`parse_url`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function.  That will give you `www.example.com` as the host name, and then you can compare that to make sure it is the hostname you expect.

Comment: For the first URL, `parse_url()` will give `host` as `www.example.com`. For the second one, it will give `path` as `www.example.com/`. You can't directly compare them.

Comment: I infer from his question that OP doesn't want to parse the second URL.  He just wants to make sure that the URL has www.example.com as the hostname.

Comment: "*How could I determine they match?*" — I think the OP wants to compare both URLs and check if `example.com` part matches.

Comment: That's right.  He wants to make sure that the hostname in the URL matches example.com.  That's why he wants to parse the URL to give him just the hostname and then compare that.  A URL is structured data and dealing with structured data as a string is asking for headaches.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the OP is trying to check if the domain part in `$first` matches the domain part in `$second`. `parse_url()` is indeed the right way to go about it, but I'm not sure how will compare them realiably? (i.e. account for extra slashes like in this example)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function DomainUrl($x) {
   $url = $x;
   if ( substr($url, 0, 7) == 'http://') { $url = substr($url, 7); }
   if ( substr($url, 0, 8) == 'https://') { $url = substr($url, 8); }
   if ( substr($url, 0, 4) == 'www.') { $url = substr($url, 4); }
   if ( substr($url, 0, 4) == 'www9.') { $url = substr($url, 4); }
   if ( strpos($url, '/') !== false) {
      $ex = explode('/', $url);
      $url = $ex['0'];
   }

      return $url;
}

$first = DomainUrl('http://www.example.com');
$second = DomainUrl('www.example.com/');

if($first == $second){
echo 'Match';
}else{
echo 'Not Match';
```

}

Comment: What if the URL is `www9.ccni.cl`?

Comment: What about `www1`, `www2`, `www999` etc?

Comment: @AmalMurali you can edit function according to your requirement

Comment: So, add an if block for every possible case? I think that's a very bad approach. This was just a side-note, I'm not the downvoter.

Comment: there is a much simplier solution called parse_url()